# mounting a transducer under a polycarbonate jar for fluid level detection

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors

I am working with a tdc1000-tdc7200 evm board for water level detection. I am trying to mount a [steminc 1MHz ultrasonic transducer](https://www.steminc.com/PZT/en/piezo-ceramic-disc-10x2mm-r-215-khz-wire-leads-smd10t2r111wl) under a polycarbonate jar to measure the water level in the jar. According to TI's recommendation ([source](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snaa266a/snaa266a.pdf)) I am using Cyanoacrylate for transducer mounting. I am wondering is there other options of adhesive that I can use for mounting? I am looking for an adhesive that does not react with water. Also TI recommended using hot glue over sensor which also absorbs. Is there a better alternative that does not hinder transducer performance?

Answer (score 2):

Water improves superglue's bonding, I'm not sure I see the problem with using it (and the hot glue) in your application.

In any case, I suspect that they specify the CA glue and hot glue because they provide a good bond, are inexpensive and reversible.

That said, I have used a variety of 2 part epoxies for mounting sensors to a variety of materials. Make sure you've got it where you want it because once it sets, there's no do-overs.

Comment: Hi DLS3141, thanks a lot for your suggestion. Can you kindly share your experience using 2 part epoxies for mounting sensors?